# Comment disappeared

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I just added a comment to a question and the comment before that was there before mine just disappeared once I submitted it.

Comment: It was deleted by its owner, a moderator or by flags.

Comment: Was it offensive, off-topic or spam?

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773915/read-cassandra-is-always-taking-60-sec-why-cassandra-thrift-php) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773914/c-php-storing-settings-in-an-integer-using-bitwise-operators)?

Answer (score 1):

It was deleted by its owner, a moderator or by flags. as [The Encapsulator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/the-encapsulator) said